# SVG version of Ubuntu One Files/Music apps for iOS

Tags: ubuntu-one, icons, ios

Is there an SVG version of the icon for either the Ubuntu One Files or Music app for iOS? The code on Launchpad only has PNG version.

Comment: If you can give a link, I can possibly try to make one(I'll probably fail, but I'll try)

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntuone-ios-client-team/ubuntuone-ios-files/trunk/view/head:/Icon%402x.png Hit the "download file" link on the right to get it

Comment: I have found a better version. Please see edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an [official rendition](http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/pictogram-file_sync-orange-hex.svg), except the rounded square is a circle. I'll modify it when I have time.

Comment: How does this deserve upvotes? I'm surprised!